# Angular Authgaurd making requests in infinite loop when error

Tags: angular

I am trying to protect my routes using authGaurd.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Response } from '../response.model';

const httpOptionsSecure = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("authToken")})
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements CanActivate {

    private baseUrl: string = environment.baseUrl + "auth/";
    private signInUrl: string = this.baseUrl + "signIn";
    private verifyUserUrl: string = this.baseUrl + "verify";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {

    }


    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            this.verifyUser().subscribe((res) => {
                if (res.code === 200 && res.isSuccess === true) observer.next(true);
                else observer.next(false);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("Err: ", err);
                this.router.navigate(['/','login']);
                observer.next(false);
            });
        });
    }

    // Verify loggedIn User
    verifyUser(): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.post<Response>(this.verifyUserUrl, {}, httpOptionsSecure);
    }
```

So whenever I am trying to go to the protected page and whenever the response from server is 400 code then the request is made again in infinte loop.

I am kind of new to angular, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just return an observable from the guard, i.e the result of `verifyUser`, no need to create a new observable. Just use `map` instead of `subscribe` and remove the wrapping observable.

Comment: @Alex as far I know map is not a method in angular 5. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: `map` is an rxjs operator and returns an Observable. Just use `this.verifyUser().map((res) => { ...  return ...` and remove the wrapping observable with `observer`. and import map :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably you are entering an infinite loop because the / path is being redirected to a path which is protected by the AuthGuard itself.

So for example. You try to access Route A, which is protected by the guard, which redirects to route B (the base route / ), and route B could be redirecting (view redirectTo attributes in the route) to route C which is also protected by the AuthGuard, resulting in the following routes.

A -> B -> C -> B -> C...

Make sure that the routing definition is correct.

Note that a route guard is activated for each Route that it is associated with

So for example if you have

```
/            <- Associated with an Auth Guard
/route1      <- Child of /
/route2      <- Child of /
```

with the following route definition

```
let routes:Routes = [
    { 
       path: '',
       canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
       children: [
         { path: '', redirectTo: 'route1', pathMatch:'full' },
         { path: 'route1' },
         { path: 'route2' }
       ]
    }
];
```

Trying to access either of the routes, will trigger the AuthGuard associated with route `/`. If you go for example, to `route1`, the auth Guard will trigger, which will redirect to `/` which will redirect again to `route1` and the cycle begins again.

I suggest to read [this documentation guide](https://angular.io/guide/router) for further information how routing works in angular.

Furthermore, the use of `Observables` does not have to do with Angular, but is `RxJS`.

Your code can be simplified as below

**For RxJS 5.5.x +**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, map, of } from 'rxjs/operators';

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.verifyUser().pipe(map((res) => {
        if (res.code === 200 && res.isSuccess === true) {
            return true;
        } 

        this.router.navigate(['/','login']);
        return false;
    }, catchError((err) => {
        console.log("Err: ", err);
        this.router.navigate(['/','login']);
        return of(false);
    }));
}

// Verify loggedIn User
verifyUser(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.verifyUserUrl, {}, httpOptionsSecure);
}
```

**For RxJS 5.4.x and below**

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.verifyUser().map((res) => {
        if (res.code === 200 && res.isSuccess === true) {
            return true;
        } 

        this.router.navigate(['/','login']);
        return false;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Err: ", err);
        this.router.navigate(['/','login']);
        return Observable.of(false);
    });
}

// Verify loggedIn User
verifyUser(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.verifyUserUrl, {}, httpOptionsSecure);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah that was my mistake , as you mentioned above I was again redirecting to a protected route. But still the `.pipe` property is not defined on the `verifyUser()`, do you think this is because I am returning `Observable<Response>` from `verifyUser()`

Comment: The pipe property is part of RxJS 5.5x. Could be you have an old version (5.4.x). I'll update my answer to cater for old versions of RxJS. Could you accept this an an answer and upvote please?

Comment: I encountered this problem and got it solved by moving the AuthGuard to the upper Module class (e.g. app.module.ts) and adding it as one of providers there

EDIT:
this is only applicable if you cant set a config to the @Injectable() annotation